# Using equals on different properties of the same collection returns no record, why?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When I use the following query:

```
MATCH (emp:Employee)
WHERE emp.supervisor_id = 159
RETURN emp
```

I get a result as 4 employees/nodes with `supervisor_id = 159`

and for this query I also get a result which is 1 employee with `employeeID = 159` :

```
MATCH (emp:Employee)
WHERE emp.employeeID = 159
RETURN emp
```

But when I use the `=` operator, it does return `(no changes, no records)`.

```
MATCH (emp:Employee)
WHERE emp.employeeID = emp.supervisor_id
RETURN emp
```

I assume it's a logic mistake, but I just can't figure it out.

Any idea pls.

Comment: what output you actually want?

Comment: I'am expecting 5 nodes. 4 nodes/employees with `supervisor_id=159` and one node/employee with `employeeID = 159`. My target at the end is to create a relationship e.g. `-[:MANAGER_OF]->` between `employeeWithID159` to other 4 different employees (separately of course).

Comment: See answer by @logisima. He doesn't say it explicitly but the reason your query does not work is that any given Employee node (emp) obviously is not it's own supervisor. Hence the need to have two Employee nodes to compare to each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your query you are searching a node with the label `Employee` that has its attribute `employeeID` equals to `supervisor_id`.

Or from what I understand, what you want is to search two differents nodes with the label `Employee`.

So your query should be this one :

```
MATCH (emp1:Employee), (emp2:Employee)
WHERE emp1.employeeID = emp2.supervisor_id
CREATE (emp1)-[:MANAGER_OF]->(emp2)
```

This query create a Cartesian product, so if you have a lot of `Employee` nodes, you should batch the creation of relationships with an  `APOC` procedure (https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) like this :

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "MATCH (emp1:Employee) RETURN emp1",
  "MATCH (emp2:Employee) WHERE emp1.employeeID = emp2.supervisor_id CREATE (emp1)-[:MANAGER_OF]->(emp2)",
 {batchSize:5000, parallel:true}
);
```

Cheers

Comment: Certainly... actually I do have 100 of employees. All of them do have attributes: `employeeID` and `superviser_id`.
The ones who have `supervisor_id=0` they are manager of other employees who have in `supervisor_id = employeeIDofOtherEmployees`.
E.g John has employeeID = 9 and supervisor_id = 0 (is a manager). 
Maria has employeeID 23 and supervisor_id = 9 (manager ID 9 - John).
Anne has employeeID 67 and supervisor_id = 9 (manager ID 9 - John).
Harry has employeeID 49 and supervisor_id = 0 (is a manager). Anne R. has employeeID 11 and supervisor_id = 49 (manager ID 49 - Harry)

Comment: The first query works fine. The second one throws the following error: `There is no procedure with the name `apoc.periodic.iterate` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.`
FYI - Her is Neo4J I'am using:  `Version:3.2.5, Edition: Community`

Comment: you have to intall APOC. Take a look at the url I have given, and go to the section `installation`

Comment: Installed, Neo4J restarted, error remains the same. As I'am not runnig Ne04J under OSx applications, i did saved the `JAR` under: `/Users/<user>/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/plugins` Any idea?

Comment: @ligisima: regarding the first query in your answer, would it help if use `UNIQUE` for the relationship? e.g `MATCH (emp1:Employee), (emp2:Employee)
WHERE emp1.employeeID = emp2.supervisor_id
CREATE UNIQUE (emp1)-[:MANAGER_OF]->(emp2)`

Comment: Use MERGE instead of CREATE UNIQUE